# maximal subset - include nonuniform node weights and node values

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve a graph theory problem.  I have an undirected graph where the nodes have node weights n and edges have edge weights g.  I want to be able to select the subgraph such that the total weight of nodes+edges is maximized.  Each node doesn’t count equally though, as each node has a nonuniform weight w.

I think this is also equivalent to the 0/1 knapsack problem except that there are additional benefits to each pair of items put into the knapsack, in addition to their singular benefit.

What is the name of such a graph theory problem?

Comment: Are the edge/node-weights non-negative? What kind of constraints do you have on the subgraphs? Is it allowed to choose any subgraph? If all weights are non-negative, then your problem is trivial because the graph itself is the optimal-value...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/13555/maximal-subset-include-nonuniform-node-weights-and-node-values

I cross-posted: it's equivalent to the quadratic knapsack problem.  I think that formally it's the maximal weighted clique problem, with weights on both nodes and edges.